# Realmで複数のプライマリキーを設定したい

Tags: swift, realm

```
class dic: Object {
     dynamic var ID1 = ""
     dynamic var ID2 = ""
     dynamic var date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1)

    override func primaryKey() -> String? {
         return "ID1";"ID2"
    }
 }
```

ID1とID2をキーにしたいんですが・・・
エラーになってしまいます。

```
Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): Can't set primary key property 'ID1' to existing value 'xxxx'.
```

教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: [composite primary key realm/swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31265666/composite-primary-key-realm-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

プライマリキーは各モデルにつき１つだけ指定することができます。複数のプロパティを組み合わせてプライマリキーとすることはできません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。複数はできないのですね。